# PHP 7 - обработка ошибок

Tags: php, исключения, php7, handlers

Описываю класс - обработчик ошибок.
Некоторые его методы:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (DEBUG) {
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', true);
    } else {
        error_reporting(0);
        ini_set('display_errors', false);
    }

    set_error_handler([$this, 'errorHandler']);
    set_exception_handler([$this, 'exceptionHandler']);
    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'fatalErrorHandler']);
}

public function errorHandler($code, $message, $file, $line)
{
    echo '<br />' . __METHOD__ . '<br />';
    // some code
    die;
}

public function fatalErrorHandler()
{
    echo '<br />' . __METHOD__ . '<br />';
    // some code
    die;
}

public function exceptionHandler(\Throwable $e)
{
    echo '<br />' . __METHOD__ . '<br />';
    // some code
    die;
}
```

Логика такая: вначале работы приложения создается экземпляр этого объекта и сохраняется в статическом свойстве главного объекта приложения, который живет всё время. 
Как видно, обработчики ошибок и исключения инициализируются в конструкторе объекта.

**Проблема** в следующем: фатальные ошибки, например Parse error, не ловятся моим обработчиком.
В чем проблема?

Comment: сдается мне что `parse error` вы при всем вашем желании в принципе не отловите.

Comment: @teran, [`register_shutdown_function` может вроде бы](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1900208).

Comment: @Other ошибки парсинга файла выпадают до выполнения скрипта в принципе.

Comment: @teran, автор одного из ответов использует `php.ini`, который инклудит код с регистрацией обработчика до выполнения самих скриптов.

Comment: @Other ну это уже извращения. Отлов ошибок уровня языка, а не программы, это не нормально.

Comment: @teran, ну это уже другой вопрос, этот обращает внимание именно на эту проблему. Хотя, для дева, это неплохая идея - красиво оформленные ошибки даже такого уровня.

Comment: Как в таком случае хотябы не выводить стандартное сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 3):

[заглядывайте в документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) хоть иногда

> Ошибки следующих типов **не могут быть обработаны** пользователем:
>   `E_ERROR`, `E_PARSE`, `E_CORE_ERROR`, `E_CORE_WARNING`, `E_COMPILE_ERROR`,
>   `E_COMPILE_WARNING`, и большинство `E_STRICT` ошибок, произошедших в
>   файле, где вызвана функция `set_error_handler()`.

Comment: [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.errors.php7.php) говорится "установите обработчик исключений с помощью set_exception_handler()".

Я предполагал, что смогу поймать эту ошибку в exceptionHandler'e, или в fatalErrorHandler'e после завершения скрипта, но не работает. Может и по этому.

Comment: @rugleb, [обратите внимание на этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1900208).